# Permalink not work when admin not login

Tags: wordpress

I had configured premalink on my wordpress. It works fine when I login in as a admin.
However, if I log out, all of the links cannot be opened. Instead, it gives me a 404 page.

Has anyone met this problem before and tell me how to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check your page properties. May be it is password protected/private or may be it is not published.

To check page properties:

- Login to Dashboard.
- Click `Pages` on left side.
- Hover on the page which you getting 404 and click `Quick Edit`

This will show all the details about your page. Check the password field, private and the Status field. The status should be `published`.

Check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing the permalinks cache by going back to the permalink options and clicking save (without changing anything). If that doesn't do the trick, make sure you've cleared your browser cache :P